# Cannot open sites via browse option in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am unable to open sites hosted in iis via the browse option in  iis but the sites are working properly when i use the url in browser, why is it like that does anyone know a resolution?

Comment: Where you have hosted application. And are you using the browser at the same machine where you have hosted?

Comment: the application is being hosted in iis .. i can access site from the browser of the same machine and also from other networks.But i am unable to access site via BROWSE option in iis

Comment: Is the server IP same as you ping the site form command prompt?

Comment: yes the server ip is the same

Comment: What are the bindings you set for this site? And what is the error page?

Comment: Looks like you posted same question with different title earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192362/open-website-pages-using-browse-option-from-iis-7-5-is-not-working-but-the-site

Comment: Bindings , all unassigned to port 80-.there is no error in error  page the browser itself doesn't open while clicking browse option in iis